# Why does changing the value of function return will change the result of function console.log?

Tags: javascript

If I put in code `return amount` and `console.log(amount)`, it will be 1250, but if I put `return balance` and `console.log(amount)`, it will be 9250! Why is it so different, I don't understand. Can you explain it to me?

```
//Declare variable;

var balance = 10500; // a global variable

var amount = steal(balance, 1250); // a global variable

//Function;

function steal(balance, amount) {

    if (amount < balance) {

        balance = balance - amount;

    }

    return amount;

}

console.log(amount); // it will be 1250, cause parameter amount = 1250
```

and if it will be `return balance`, `console.log(amount)` = 9250

Comment: You should used scoped variables instead such as `let`

Comment: The **returned** value of `steal()` is assigned back to `amount` variable: `var amount = steal(balance, 1250);`. That is why results are different depending on what you return from `steal()`.

Comment: Your function should `return balance` instead of `return amount`

Comment: So your question is if you return a different value, why is the result is different? Well of course it is; that's what return is for. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Function Parameter argument or global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081440/javascript-function-parameter-argument-or-global-variable)

Comment: Thanks you guys!

Comment: @Shidersz thanks you very much!!!!!OMG am happy now!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

beacuse when you return amount, value of steal function sit on amount variable and this is equal to 1250 and when you return balance, value of balance (balance - amount = 9250) sit on amount variable

```
var amount = steal(balance, 1250); // if return amount result will be 1250
var amount = steal(balance, 1250); // if return balance result will be 9250
```

return for steal function sit on amount variable!!!
this is easy!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your log statement logs the variable declared at the top:

```
var amount = steal(balance, 1250);
```

Since you set it to the return value of `steal`, it shouldn’t surprise you that it changes your content based on the return.

---

Functions create a new variable scope and arguments live in this scope. The parameter `amount` does not change the variable `amount` in the outer scope:

```
function steal(balance, amount) {
  // amount is a new variable unrelated to the amount from above
}
```

If that weren’t the case, that could hard to debug bugs.